# Convert group_concat of MYSQL to SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in MySQL which is using `group_concat`. I want to convert it into a SQL Server query.

```
select 
    apj.package_id, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT concat(asset.asset_id, '-', asset.name) SEPARATOR '||')'asset_names'
from 
    stg.asset_package_join apj (NOLOCK), stg.asset asset (NOLOCK) 
where 
    asset.id = apj.asset_id 
group by 
    apj.package_id
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi Krishnraj, I am using sql server 2012.